# Accessing .in files from a different directory

Tags: c++

Suppose that I add a program to path that is dependent on a file name "test.in". I programmed this in C++ so I used ifstream fin("test.in") without specifying the directory. Now if I were to run this program from a different directory, would the program be able to access the file "test.in"?

Comment: You could also have simply _tried it_.

Comment: All you have to do is specify the path to where the file is stored when you declare the ifstream. Look it up online.

Comment: _"would the program be able to access the file "test.in"?"_ No.

Comment: @miro: Actually, hardcoding an absolute path is a bad idea. Look it up online.

Comment: It doesnt have to be absolute path just simply from where his source code is

Comment: @miro: No, the path is relative to the execution working directory, not where the source code is, or even where the executable is. Look it up online.

Comment: This is something you could have **tried for yourself**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, this has nothing to do with the file extension, which is merely a convention given as part of the filename.

Secondly, you were *always* using a relative path. Even when you were running your program "from the same directory" as `test.in`, you were reliant on the "working directory" of your shell context being the same as the directory in which the executable and the file reside.

This is not always the case.

For example:

```
~/myProject:# ls
test.in
program

~/myProject:# ./program
```

This is okay, because your shell is at `~/myProject`, and so is `test.in`.

However, if you'd written:

```
~/myProject:# cd ..
~:# ./myProject/program
```

…then your `test.in` file wouldn't be found, as it does not exist in `~`. It exists in `~/myProject`. It doesn't matter that the executable itself is also found in `~/myProject`.

This is actually desirable behaviour, as it allows flexibility from the shell. Ideally you would allow support for piping/redirecting the file to the process instead (`program < test.in` — now there are no assumptions baked into your code *at all*!), but we can save that for another day.

For now, you seem to be concerned about what happens if you move the executable away. Don't worry: *just use this feature!*

```
~:# mv myProject/program .
~:# cd myProject
~/myProject:# ../myProject
```

Your working directory is the directory in which `test.in` resides, so it will be found via the relative path given in your program code.